# creat a graphic picture from a video

Tags: animation

I'm not familiar with animation software. 
I recorded fish larvae locomotion in mp4/ AVI format. i need to present it in a graphic style . Anybody knows about the proper software? 
Actually I need to track fish movement and finally should draw lines showing the routes. Yesterday i bought Adobe After Effect as it was recommended by user 287001. It kept me awake for some hours. I still need more help to point some traceable details in the objective ( fish larvae) and run the software to analysis the motions.

Comment: Could you give some examples? What exactly are you trying to achieve and exactly is "a graphical style"? What software do you have available or what requirements do have for any software recommendations?

Comment: Do you mean grabing a frame as a base for a cartoon?

Comment: I need to track fish movement and finally should draw lines showing the routes. Yesterday i bought  Adobe After Effect as it was recommended by user  287001. It kept me awake for some hours. I still need more help to point some traceable details in the objective ( fish larvae) and run the software to analysis the motions.

Comment: There you go that editted question is totally different from your original one. Tracking is a different thing though dedicated animation packages do have trackers. But even automatic tracking is possible.

Answer (score 1):

a first aid is to use some line art or cartoonize  effect. It's common in pro level and also in low cost video editing software.

The demand of cartoonized videos is substantial. There exist many pieces of dedicated video editing software and web services for that task. Do a Google search "transform video to animation" or "cartoonize video". You will get plenty of hits.

Highest quality results need animation software. There you must recreate the frames as drawings. Original video frames can be used as reference.
Unfortunately the job also takes much more effort this way. Animation software helps to streamline the process remarkably but it does not do the work for you.

ADDENDUM:

- If you have a multitrack video editor that allows you to make drawn overlays, you can frame by frame draw the motion onto a free track. Not definitely a piece of cake if there exist many, say 20 feet that must all be tracked or some otherwise rich outline must be drawn. Finally you can hide the original video. A little, but not much more complicated is to copy one frame at a time via the clipboard to a drawing program and to draw the overlay there.
- You can also try some cartoonizing filter and erase the exessive crap off as an alternative for drawing the overlays yourself. Finally you can paste the overlay back as a frame into a separate video track. Alternatively you can directly make a GIF animation in the drawing program. Recycling via a multilayer drawing program (Photoshop, GIMP etc...) makes possible to reuse those parts that have not deformed, but possibly moved.
- As commented, this is possible to get half-way automated. The most advanced  video tools, like Adobe After Effects do it. You must outline the wanted object area in the beginning and point some trackable details in it. The software analyzes the motion and redraws the outline of the wanted object. As commented, search for "rotoscope". Below stands one of the search hits: [rotoscope  - an example story](https://www.videomaker.com/article/f06/17164-the-horrors-of-rotoscoping)

Comment: Drawing on frames is called rotoscoping and even specialized software exists that can do it semiautomatically

Comment: Thank you all. I have almost 5 hours video and i need something as  Adobe After Effect ( as it is explained in your comment) or rotoscope. Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: @mehdishakouri 5 hours! forget animation. Any semimanual way will take too long. Even at a lightspeed pace of  a second per picture means 125 hours of work, with breaks and workdays its one manmonth of the most booring yet intensive work you have ever done in your life. You really need something more dedicated for tracking.